# SourceCookifier in Notepad++ not always detecting Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, notepad++

If I open the file Fred.js in Notepad++ and activate SourceCookifier it should display a list of all the functions in the script.

However it reports function F_1 but not function F_2

```
function F_1()
{
        var ann             = 1234      //<--- OK without ;
        var bob             = 1234 ;    //<----- ; must be present, so F_1 is reported.
        console.log ("Hello world")     //<--- OK without ;
}
function F_2()
{
        var ann             = 1234      //<--- OK without ;
        var bob             = 1234      //<----- ; should be present, so F_2 is not reported.
        console.log ("Hello world")     //<--- OK without ;
}
```

The only difference is that in F_2 the terminating ";" character is absent.

I guess it is a bug, but maybe I am doing something wrong?

System: Windows 7, 32 bit, Notepad++ v.7.7(2019), SourceCookifier v0.7.3.0.

---

Update (20201129) I notice that the same problem has been reported on SourceForge two years ago (2018):- [by Tarek Faham](https://sourceforge.net/p/sourcecookifier/discussion/1067263/thread/154f4bb7/)

Answer (score 0):

(1) Pending a solution (such as a possible bugfix to the SourceCookifier code) I found that if you save your .js file with filetype: **`.html`** and edit that in Notepad++ then the problem does not present.

Sadly some of the other javascript element types will not be reported when in "html" mode.

Of course you must remember to resave it with  filetype:**`.js`** and overwrite the older .js version if you have done any edits.

(2) Use free online validation tool like [validatejavascript.com](https://validatejavascript.com/). However you will need to apply an appropriate ruleset.  With "standard" ruleset I got scores of (to me: trivial) errors (like "space after open parenthesis"). in 2300 lines of code.  With "custom" ruleset (no boxes checked) it found zero errors.  So you have to know what sort of error to look out for!

---

Update 20201202

The following code caused problems if the `;` characters were absent:-

```
if      ( cVal == "£") {cVal = "$"  ; }  
else if ( cVal == "@") {cVal = "\\" ; }
```